# Using RegEx to balance match parenthesis

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to create a .NET RegEx expression that will properly balance out my parenthesis. I have the following RegEx expression:

```
func([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\(.*\)
```

The string I am trying to match is this:

```
"test -> funcPow((3),2) * (9+1)"
```

What should happen is Regex should match everything from `funcPow` until the second closing parenthesis. It should stop after the second closing parenthesis. Instead, it is matching all the way to the very last closing parenthesis. RegEx is returning this:

```
"funcPow((3),2) * (9+1)"
```

It should return this:

```
"funcPow((3),2)"
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Regular Expressions can definitely do balanced parentheses matching.  It can be tricky, and requires a couple of the more advanced Regex features, but it's not too hard.

Example:

```
var r = new Regex(@"
    func([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*) # The func name

    \(                      # First '('
        (?:                 
        [^()]               # Match all non-braces
        |
        (?<open> \( )       # Match '(', and capture into 'open'
        |
        (?<-open> \) )      # Match ')', and delete the 'open' capture
        )+
        (?(open)(?!))       # Fails if 'open' stack isn't empty!

    \)                      # Last ')'
", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Balanced matching groups have a couple of features, but for this example, we're only using the capture deleting feature.  The line `(?<-open> \) )` will match a `)` and delete the previous "open" capture.

The trickiest line is `(?(open)(?!))`, so let me explain it.  `(?(open)` is a conditional expression that only matches if there is an "open" capture.  `(?!)` is a negative expression that always fails.  Therefore, `(?(open)(?!))` says "if there is an open capture, then fail".

[Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition) was pretty helpful too.

Comment: I changed the line `[^()]*               # Match all non-braces` so it matches () with nothing inside

Answer (score 22):

Using balanced groups, it is:

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"func([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\(((?<BR>\()|(?<-BR>\))|[^()]*)+\)");

var match = rx.Match("funcPow((3),2) * (9+1)");

var str = match.Value; // funcPow((3),2)
```

`(?<BR>\()|(?<-BR>\))` are a [Balancing Group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition) (the `BR` I used for the name is for `Brackets`). It's more clear in this way *`(?<BR>`*\(*`)|(?<-BR>`*\)*`)`* perhaps, so that the `\(` and `\)` are more "evident".

If you really hate yourself (and the world/your fellow co-programmers) enough to use these things, I suggest using the `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` and "sprinkling" white space everywhere :-)

Comment: I think you are missing the last critical part, `(?(BR)(?!))`

Comment: @ScottRippey No. There are other expressions after the closing `)`. The OP question was VERY precise. He wants `funcsomething()`, not to parse the entire expression. So the first "unbalanced" bracket I find is the closing bracket of my sub-expression. `funcPow((3),2) * (9+1) -> funcPow((3),2)`

Comment: Oh, I realized that `(?(BR)(?!))` is only to ensure the opening brace has a closing brace.  Microsoft's website: "The final subexpression, (?(Open)(?!)), indicates whether the nesting constructs in the input string are properly balanced "

Comment: @ScottRippey Exactly as you wrote :-) Note that it's a combination of an alternation construct http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36xybswe(v=VS.71).aspx of type `(?(name)yes|no)` with a negative lookahead expression `(?!)` that always fails. So it reads "if there is a capture of name `name` then fail"

Comment: This was a good discussion :-)  We think alike. Too alike. Now I must destroy you. I'm sorry.

Comment: Just for the record, the difference between including the `(?(BR)(?!))` and not including it is that, without it, the expression will _match_ up to and including the last closing parenthesis if ther are not _enough_ closing parentheses. With it, the expression as a whole will _not match_.

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expressions only work on [Regular Languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). This means that a regular expression can find things of the sort "any combination of a's and b's".(`ab` or `babbabaaa` etc) But they can't find "*n* a's, one b, *n* a's".(`a^n b a^n`) Regular expressions can't guarantee that the first set of a's matches the second set of a's.

Because of this, they aren't able to match equal numbers of opening and closing parenthesis. It would be easy enough to write a function that traverses the string one character at a time. Have two counters, one for opening paren, one for closing. increment the pointers as you traverse the string, if `opening_paren_count != closing_parent_count` return false.

Comment: That's as may be, but **regexes** can be used on almost any kind of text as long as you understand their limitations.  Recursive/balanced patterns are ugly and (IMO) seldom worth the effort, but they *are* supported by many regex flavors.

Answer (score -1):

```
func[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\((([^()])|(\([^()]*\)))*\)
```

You can use that, but if you're working with .NET, there may be better alternatives.

This part you already know:

```
 func[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\( --weird part-- \)
```

The --weird part-- part just means; `(` allow any character `.`, or `|` any section `(.*)` to exist as many times as it wants `)*`.  The only issue is, you can't match any character `.`, you have to use `[^()]` to exclude the parenthesis.

```
(([^()])|(\([^()]*\)))*
```

Comment: You should specify that this will work with only one level of nesting.

Comment: @ScottRippey: It still works if there is a function within that function.  The | condition handles that.  Can you give an example where this regex would provide a false match?

Comment: It works correctly, and does exactly as the OP asked, so it is a good answer. However, it is hard coded to only match one level of nesting, so it would fail to match: `func(a(b(c)d)e)`. It is unclear if the OP needed this.