# Regular Expressions Balancing Group

Tags: c#, regex, balancing-groups

I am trying to match balancing braces ({}) in strings. For example, I want to balance the following:

```
if (a == 2)
{
  doSomething();
  { 
     int x = 10;
  }
}

// this is a comment

while (a <= b){
  print(a++);
}
```

I came up with this regex from MSDN, but it doesn't work well. I want to extract multiple nested matching sets of {}. I am only interested in the parent match

```
   "[^{}]*" +
   "(" + 
   "((?'Open'{)[^{}]*)+" +
   "((?'Close-Open'})[^{}]*)+" +
   ")*" +
   "(?(Open)(?!))";
```

Comment: It's impossible for a standard regex. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns

Comment: But C#/.NET supports balancing groups, so it should be possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're pretty close.

Adapted from the second answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898310/using-regex-to-balance-match-parenthesis) (I use that as my canonical "balancing xxx in C#/.NET regex engine" answer, upvote it if it helped you! It has helped me in the past):

```
var r = new Regex(@"
[^{}]*                  # any non brace stuff.
\{(                     # First '{' + capturing bracket
    (?:                 
    [^{}]               # Match all non-braces
    |
    (?<open> \{ )       # Match '{', and capture into 'open'
    |
    (?<-open> \} )      # Match '}', and delete the 'open' capture
    )+                  # Change to * if you want to allow {}
    (?(open)(?!))       # Fails if 'open' stack isn't empty!
)\}                     # Last '}' + close capturing bracket
"; RegexOptions.IgnoreWhitespace);
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks. I just have a minor problem I am trying to fix. It's reading a lot of unrelated lines before the first brace {

Comment: Is this a way to use this -- var input = "abc{def{123}}"; Match m = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

Comment: [^{}]*\{((?:[^{}]|(?<open>\{)|(?<-open>\}))+(?(open)(?!)))\}

Comment: I don't believe this works. It fails on a pretty simple case.

   return Regex.IsMatch"{{}}", @"[^{}]*\{((?:[^{}]|(?<open>\{)|(?<-open>\}))+(?(open)(?!)))\}"); // returns True
   return Regex.IsMatch("{{{}{}}", @"[^{}]*\{((?:[^{}]|(?<open>\{)|(?<-open>\}))+(?(open)(?!)))\}"); // returns True, Expected False

Comment: @JJS it returns true on the last one because it matches the balanced part `{{}{}}` not the entire string. If you want to force it against the entire string anchor the pattern with `^` and `$`

Comment: Thanks for the tip @mathematical.coffee.
Regex.IsMatch("{{{}{}}", @"^[^{}]*\{((?:[^{}]|(?<open>\{)|(?<-open>\}))+(?(open)(?!)))\}$") does in fact return False, as I expected.

Comment: Is there a way to use the same balancing for for all types of braces (e.g. parenthesis, curly braces and square brackets)?