# Call Function when User Types Certain Keyword

Tags: vb.net

Okay, so I am working on a small scripting language using a VB Console Application.

I want the user to input "say('something')" and it calls the function I made named "say", is there a way to call the function and still use the following code:

```
Module Module1

Sub say(sayline)
    Console.WriteLine(sayline)
End Sub


Sub Main()

    Dim cmd As String
    Console.WriteLine(">")
    Do
        Console.Write("")
        cmd = Console.ReadLine()
        If cmd IsNot Nothing Then cmd
    Loop While cmd IsNot Nothing



End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: What this line suppose to do? `If cmd IsNot Nothing Then cmd`

Comment: That line not even compile

Comment: Check this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898310/using-regex-to-balance-match-parenthesis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898310/using-regex-to-balance-match-parenthesis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to call the method `say` upon typing the word `say(something)` and display the word `something`, then you can just have a certain condition that if the user types the word `say` within the input then call `say method` else, do whatever you want to do under else portion. Parse the input and omit the word `say` from the input and display it then.

You can have your code this way for example. (I just copied your code and added some codes to meet what you wanted... in my understanding)

```
Module Module1
  Sub say(ByVal sayline)
    Console.WriteLine(sayline)
  End Sub

  Sub Main()
    Dim cmd As String
    Do
        Console.Write("> ")
        cmd = Console.ReadLine()
        Try
            If cmd IsNot Nothing And cmd.Substring(0, 3).ToUpper().Equals("SAY") Then
                say(parseInput(cmd))
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("message here")
        End Try
    Loop While cmd IsNot Nothing
  End Sub

  Function parseInput(ByVal cmd As String) As String
    Dim input As String = ""
    For index As Integer = 3 To cmd.Length - 1
        If Char.IsLetter(cmd) Then
            input += cmd.Substring(index, 1)
        Else
            input = input
        End If
    Next
    Return input
  End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Actually, this approach is absolutely incorrect.
What if I enter `saying`? It will call `say('ng'). As I understand, the author wants to write a script language and using `substring` for it is not a good beginning. Btw, `input = input` is fun.

Comment: Throw exception if `cmd.Length < 3` too.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot just call a method from user's string. You need to interpret the entered data.

First, you need to split your method name and arguments so that entered `"say('something')"` will transform to `say` and `something`. Remember that user can enter wrong data and you need to check if this call is correct - it's all about syntactic and lexical analysis. I hope you understand how to do this because it is pretty difficult.

Then, you need to check if you have a method called `say`. In case of plain and simple structure, `switch` construction will be enough. If your have such method, then pass `something` argument to this method. Else, output something like "unknown method".