# How can I return a list of words using regex, but define a word to also includes contents of a token?

Tags: c#, regex

So if my expression is:

```
var exp = "a b c (d e f (g h i) {foo}) {j k {l m}} n o p";
```

And my "tokens" are **()** and **{}**  So once you hit an opening **(** or **{** it should return everything until the the closing token is found, even if there are nested tokens

The matches for this example should be:

```
a
b
c
(d e f (g h i) {foo})
{j k {l m}}
n
o
p
```

The submitted duplicate question doesn't really seem to address my issue of matching WORDS.

Comment: is that the brackets are 1 depth deep? What if your input is `foo(bar(buzz)jhjsd)` ?

Comment: unlimited depth.  in your example it would return `foo, (bar(buzz)jhjsd)`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, Yes I seen that.

Comment: @hwnd: you only need to handle the two cases separately, the first that ignores the curly brackets, the second that ignores the parenthesis.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, I figure you mean using alternation for each case.

Comment: @hwnd: yes `<°)))))>` and you can reuse the same group name.

Comment: Did someone delete a comment?  These comment seem out of context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the balanced groups were certainly involved.  From [Using RegEx to balance match parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898310/using-regex-to-balance-match-parenthesis) I was able to create the following, wihch I presented in a format that will work in the compiler then one broken up in order to explain what is going on

```
        string pattern = @"\w|\(((?<BR>\()|(?<-BR>\))|[^()]*)+\)|\{((?<BR>\{)|(?<-BR>\})|[^{}]*)+\}";


        string pattern = @"
           \w|                                   #Match any word OR
           \(((?<BR>\()|(?<-BR>\))|[^()]*)+\)|   #Match a () balanced group OR
           \{((?<BR>\{)|(?<-BR>\})|[^{}]*)+\}    #Match a {} balanced group
         ";
```

This returns the 8 values I expected.  What was missing from the balanced group example, was a simple **\w** matching expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = Regex.Matches(input, @"((\(.+\))|(\{.+\})|(\w+))")
                  .Cast<Match>()
                  .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                  .ToList();
```