# regex where parenthesis might not be balanced

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have to pull some text out of a PDF stream as a string. This stream will contain both the markup to describe the appearance of the text, and the text itself. The string that I receive that my regex will have to run on will never contain any carriage returns or line feeds. The areas of text that I am interested in will always be inside parenthesis (and there will potentially be parenthesis inside parenthesis), and after the final parenthesis there will be the letters 'Tj'. In short, what I am after will always follow the convention:

```
(.....) Tj
```

At the moment, the regex I have is working, as long as the parenthesis are all balanced:

```
\((?:[^()]|(?'paren'\()|(?'-paren'\)))+(?(paren)(?!))\)
```

However if the text itself contains unbalanced parethesis, this regex will not pull what I want, and I am not sure how to change it to be able to handle unbalanced parenthesis.

Here is a sample of what would be considered a 'normal' string:

```
q  Q  /Tx BMC  q  0 0 471.34 407.34 re  W  n  BT  1 0 0 1 2 397.16 Tm  /Helv 12 Tf  0 g  (RE:  Request for Additional Information) Tj
```

So obviously, I want to get the string 'RE:  Request for Additional Information' out of that.

and here is an example case that my regex will fail on (I have added unbalanced parenthesis):

```
q  Q  /Tx BMC  q  0 0 471.34 407.34 re  W  n  BT  1 0 0 1 2 397.16 Tm  /Helv 12 Tf  0 g  (RE:  Request for (Additional Information) Tj 0 g  1 0 0 1 2 383.29 Tm  0 g  (     13. Processing TT Instructions -) Audit Note 12) Tj  0 g  1 0 0 1 2 369.42 Tm  0 g  () Tj  0 g  1 0 0 1 2 355.55 Tm  0 g  (Dear test:) Tj  0 g  1 0 0 1 2 341.68 Tm  0 g  () Tj  0 g  1 0 0 1 2 327.8 Tm  0 g  (Thank you for the more random words here.  )Unfortunately, more words here) terminating (words here) Tj
```

There are also empty sets of parenthesis in here, that look like:

```
() Tj
```

These represent carriage returns and line feeds when the PDF is rendered. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

--- UPDATE to answer questions below

Any type of user input can be placed between the open and closing parenthesis. I want to extract all content as provided, however that may be, even if the user forgot to balance their parenthesis. The only guarantee is that the text between the parenthesis is user input, but however they input the text is up to them, so it does NOT follow a predefined format such as *([abbrev]: [content])*, etc. The content is only guaranteed to be between an open parens, a close parens, and after the close parens will be the letters 'Tj'.

Comment: Regualr expressions can not handle arbitrarily nested parentheses. The language of matching parentheses is itself, not regular.

Comment: I haven't figured out your regex, however, I have played with your examples, and I think that this doable, although you might have to do more than one search and replace. In the example "(RE:  Request for (Additional Information)", you can extract "RE:  Request for (Additional Information" by replacing the beginning of the line followed by any number of any character OTHER THAN open parenthesis, then do the numbered save. The key is that .* gets the LONGEST match, so it will bypass the first open parenthesis (RE: ... and go all the way to (Additional ... I'll look at this again tomorrow.

Comment: By the way, in your example of a case in which your regex will fail, there are multiple matches. Will those all be on one line, or one per line?

Comment: @ThomasHedden the program I am using reads the entire stream in as a single line, however long that might be. I should probably also note that the regex I pasted above was done in .NET. I modeled my solution after this post: http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/7899205/4387192

Comment: What kind of strings (in format) can be in place of **RE:  Request for Additional Information**? Is it always in the same format (*[abbreviation]: [long description]*)?

Comment: @resu: You have not specified the expected result for the second sample string.

Comment: I don't know .NET regex, but I have a sed regular expression that will produce these strings:
RE:  Request for Additional Information
RE:  Request for (Additional Information
13. Processing TT Instructions -) Audit Note 12
Dear test:
Thank you for the more random words here.  )Unfortunately, more words here) terminating (words here
... AS LONG AS each (...) Tj expression is on a separate line. Also, it still fails on () Tj (empty string). If you're interested I'll post it. (It's hard to post the expression because the SO user interface needs a lot of characters escaped.)

Comment: The short answer for matching balanced constructs with regex is "recursion," and the answer looks like this: `\((?>[^()]|(?R))*\)`  I won't do it justice trying to explain it, but this link should help you:  http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html

Comment: @ThomasHedden, please feel free to post whatever you have, any help is welcome. The content will be provided as a single, uninterrupted string. I can try and programmatically insert the line feeds, but I worry that any programmatic solution would run into the same unbalanced parenthesis problem.

Comment: Hello resu, I think that Luv2code has a good point (that I mentioned, too) that you might have to process the input more than once to get your desired output. One thing I can say is that to overcome the "() Tj" (empty strings) you'll probably need "negative lookahead". I am pretty sure that this is impossible in sed. I don't know about .NET. But I am 99% sure that this can be done in perl. I'll post what I have pretty soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, I can't help with .NET, but I can give you an expression that might help. I think the solution requires "negative lookahead", and perl offers that. The problem is that I haven't used perl in so long I've forgotten how to get it to march through the entire stream. If I break the stream into chunks of "(...) Tj", each on its own line, my script will work on all your examples:

```
$ cat pdf_data_line_by_line.txt
q  Q  /Tx BMC  q  0 0 471.34 407.34 re  W  n  BT  1 0 0 1 2 397.16 Tm  /Helv 12 Tf  0 g  (RE:  Request for Additional Information) Tj
q  Q  /Tx BMC  q  0 0 471.34 407.34 re  W  n  BT  1 0 0 1 2 397.16 Tm  /Helv 12 Tf  0 g  (RE:  Request for (Additional Information) Tj
0 g  1 0 0 1 2 383.29 Tm  0 g  (     13. Processing TT Instructions -) Audit Note 12) Tj
0 g  1 0 0 1 2 369.42 Tm  0 g  () Tj
0 g  1 0 0 1 2 355.55 Tm  0 g  (Dear test:) Tj
0 g  1 0 0 1 2 341.68 Tm  0 g  () Tj
0 g  1 0 0 1 2 327.8 Tm  0 g  (Thank you for the more random words here.  )Unfortunately, more words here) terminating (words here) Tj
$ cat get_pdf_text.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<>) {
   # find some text
   if ( /[^(]*\((?!\)).*\) Tj/ ) {
      # strip off leading junk
      s/[^(]*\((?!\))[ ]*([^)].*)\) Tj/$1/;
      # output saved part of match
      print $_;
      print "YOUR DELIMITER HERE\n";
   }
}
$ cat pdf_data_line_by_line.txt | ./get_pdf_text.pl
RE:  Request for Additional Information
YOUR DELIMITER HERE
RE:  Request for (Additional Information
YOUR DELIMITER HERE
13. Processing TT Instructions -) Audit Note 12
YOUR DELIMITER HERE
Dear test:
YOUR DELIMITER HERE
Thank you for the more random words here.  )Unfortunately, more words here) terminating (words here
YOUR DELIMITER HERE
```

However, if I combine the examples into a single stream, it stops after the first one. I tried using "g" at the end of the 's' command, but it didn't help:

```
$ cat pdf_data_single_stream.txt
q  Q  /Tx BMC  q  0 0 471.34 407.34 re  W  n  BT  1 0 0 1 2 397.16 Tm  /Helv 12 Tf  0 g  (RE:  Request for (Additional Information) Tj 0 g  1 0 0 1 2 383.29 Tm  0 g  (     13. Processing TT Instructions -) Audit Note 12) Tj 0 g  1 0 0 1 2 369.42 Tm  0 g  () Tj  0 g  1 0 0 1 2 355.55 Tm  0 g  (Dear test:) Tj 0 g  1 0 0 1 2 341.68 Tm  0 g  () Tj  0 g  1 0 0 1 2 327.8 Tm  0 g  (Thank you for the more random words here.  )Unfortunately, more words here) terminating (words here) Tj
$ cat pdf_data_single_stream.txt | ./get_pdf_text.pl
RE:  Request for (Additional Information) Tj 0 g  1 0 0 1 2 383.29 Tm  0 g  (     13. Processing TT Instructions -) Audit Note 12) Tj 0 g  1 0 0 1 2 369.42 Tm  0 g  () Tj  0 g  1 0 0 1 2 355.55 Tm  0 g  (Dear test:) Tj 0 g  1 0 0 1 2 341.68 Tm  0 g  () Tj  0 g  1 0 0 1 2 327.8 Tm  0 g  (Thank you for the more random words here.  )Unfortunately, more words here) terminating (words here
YOUR DELIMITER HERE
```

The replacement string ...

```
s/[^(]*\((?!\))[ ]*([^)].*)\) Tj/$1/
```

... does the following: find zero or more characters that are NOT '(', followed by a single '(' that is NOT followed by a ')' (this is where you need negative lookahead, and this eliminates '() Tj' cases), followed by zero or more spaces, then remember {the one following character if it is not a ')' and zero or more following characters}, if followed by a ') Tj', and replace all that by the remembered string.
If anyone can suggest the (probably very simple) way to get the script to march all the way through the stream, then that should solve the problem at hand.

Comment: thank you for posting your answer. It worked, once you split on the 'Tj' to get everything into lines, as you have done above.