# Get Expression in Named Capture

Tags: c#, regex

I am providing a textbox for one to enter a Regular Expression to match filenames. I plan to detect any named capture groups that they provide with the Regex method `GetGroupNames()`.

I want to get the expression that they entered inside each named capture group.

As an example, they might enter a regular expression like this:

```
December (?<FileYear>\d{4}) Records\.xlsx
```

Is there a method or means to get the sub-expression `\d{4}` apart from manually parsing the regular expression string?

Comment: as a side note, `/d` should be `\d`, and `.` should be escaped `\.` https://regex101.com/r/E9njt1/1

Comment: Ah thanks... I typed the /d wrong and the \. I forgot about.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an ugly brute force extension for parsing without using another Regex to detect the subexpression (or subpattern):

```
    public static string GetSubExpression(this Regex pRegex, string pCaptureName)
    {
        string sRegex = pRegex.ToString();
        string sGroupText = @"(?<" + pCaptureName + ">";
        int iStartSearchAt = sRegex.IndexOf(sGroupText) + sGroupText.Length;
        string sRemainder = sRegex.Substring(iStartSearchAt);
        string sThis;
        string sPrev = "";
        int iOpenParenCount = 0;
        int iEnd = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sRemainder.Length; i++)
        {
            sThis = sRemainder.Substring(i, 1);
            if (sThis == ")" && sPrev != @"\" && iOpenParenCount == 0)
            {
                iEnd = i;
                break;
            }
            else if (sThis == ")" && sPrev != @"\")
            {
                iOpenParenCount--;
            }
            else if (sThis == "(" && sPrev != @"\")
            {
                iOpenParenCount++;
            }
            sPrev = sThis;
        }
        return sRemainder.Substring(0, iEnd);
    }
```

The usage looks like this:

```
    Regex reFromUser = new Regex(txtFromUser.Text);
    string[] asGroupNames = reFromUser.GetGroupNames();
    int iItsInt;
    foreach (string sGroupName in asGroupNames)
    {
        if (!Int32.TryParse(sGroupName, out iItsInt)) //don't want numbered groups
        {
            string sSubExpression = reParts.GetSubExpression(sGroupName);
            //Do what I need to do with the sub-expression
        }
    }
```

Now, if you would like to generate test or sample data, you can use the NuGet package called "Fare" in the following way after you get a sub-expression:

```
            //Generate test data for it
            Fare.Xeger X = new Fare.Xeger(sSubExpression);
            string sSample = X.Generate();
```

Comment: I would recommend checking for escaped parentheses too `\(` and `\)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a regular expression to match the capturing groups in a regular expression. Idea is from this post [Using RegEx to balance match parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898310/using-regex-to-balance-match-parenthesis#7899205):

```
\(\?\<(?<MyGroupName>\w+)\>
(?<MyExpression>
((?<BR>\()|(?<-BR>\))|[^()]*)+
)
\)
```

or more concisely...

```
\(\?\<(?<MyGroupName>\w+)\>(?<MyExpression>((?<BR>\()|(?<-BR>\))|[^()]*)+)\)
```

and to use it might look like this:

```
string sGetCaptures = @"\(\?\<(?<MyGroupName>\w+)\>(?<MyExpression>((?<BR>\()|(?<-BR>\))|[^()]*)+)\)";
MatchCollection MC = Regex.Matches(txtFromUser.Text, sGetCaptures );
foreach (Match M in MC)
{
    string sGroupName = M.Groups["MyGroupName"].Value;
    string sSubExpression = M.Groups["MyExpression"].Value;
    //Do what I need to do with the sub-expression
    MessageBox.Show(sGroupName + ":" + sSubExpression);
}
```

And for the example in the original question, the message box would return `FileYear:\d{4}`

Answer (score 0):

This pattern `(?<=\(\?<\w+\>)([^)]+)` will give you all the named match capture expression with the name of the capture. It uses a negative look behind to make sure the text matched will have a `(?<...>` before it.

---

```
string data = @"December (?<FileYear>\d{4}) Records\.xlsx";
string pattern = @"(?<=\(\?<\w+\>)([^)]+)";

Regex.Matches(data, pattern)
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select(mt => mt.Groups[0].Value)
```

returns one item of

`\d{4}`

While the data such as `(?<FileMonth>[^\s]+)\s+(?<FileYear>\d{4}) Records\.xlsx` would return two matches:

`[^\s]+`

`\d{4}`

Comment: This did not handle "(?<Year>\d{2}(\d)(\d))", only returning "\d{2}(\d".

Comment: @JohnKurtz you did not provide that as a scenario/example. Please add all data example scenarios.

Comment: Ah, you are correct, your answer meets the question. The handling of extra parenthesis was discussed in the other answers.

Comment: @JohnKurtz If my understanding of what you need to do is correct, you may find you will have too many scenarios to be handled by just one regex, but need a parser.