# Replace beginning and end of string with unique midle?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have lots of code like below:

```
PlusEnvironment.EnumToBool(Row["block_friends"].ToString())
```

I need to convert them to something like this.

```
Row["block_friends"].ToString() == "1"
```

The value that gets passed to EnumToBool is **always unique**, meaning there is no guarantee that itll be passed by a row, it could be passed by a variable, or even a method that returns a string.

I've tried doing this with regex, but its sort of sketchy and doesn't work 100%.

```
PlusEnvironment\.EnumToBool\((.*)\)
```

I need to do this in Visual Studio's find and replace. I'm using VS 17.

Comment: Probably more trouble than it's worth but you can maybe use a RegEx to match balanced parentheses: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7899205/224370  Unless you have thousands it would be easier to just to fix the first part with a normal replace and then manually fix the syntax errors for the remainder replacing the ) with =="1" until all the red has gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a few places where `PlusEnvironment.EnumToBool()` was called, I would have done the same thing that @IanMercer suggested: just replace `PlusEnvironment.EnumToBool(` with empty string and the fix all the syntax errors.

@IanMercer has also given you a link to super cool, advanced regex usage that will help you.

But if you are skeptical about using such a complex regex on hundreds of files, here is what I would have done:

Define my own `PlusEnvironment` class with `EnumToBool` functionality in my own namespace. And then just replace the `using Plus;` line with `using <my own namespace>;` in those hundreds of files. That way my changes will be limited to only the `using...` line, 1 line per file, and it will be simple find and replace, no regex needed.

(Note: I'm assuming that you don't want to use PlusEnvironment, or the complete library and hence you want to do this type of replacement.)

Answer (score -1):

in Find and Replace Window:
Find:
PlusEnvironment\.EnumToBool\((.*))

Replace:
$1 == "1"

Make sure "Use Regular Expressions" is selected

Comment: I think the Op knows how to use VS, the question is how to match balanced parentheses when there may be another set inside.