# Regex: Get anything between any curly braces

Tags: c#, regex, .net-core

Regex noob here

I have the following string:

```
This is a message {key1} {{key2}} {{{key3}}}, and includes {key4}.
```

I'm trying to extract anything between the outer curly braces. Expected matches:

```
key1
{key2}
{{key3}}
key4
```

Most SO examples cover matches on a single curly brace or a double curly brace, but not both or any variation of. Expressions like `[^{\}]+(?=})` will get me the content between the inner braces, and `(?<=\{).*?(?=\})` will get the leading braces except the first, but not the trailing ones.

Comment: Try a capturing group with lookarounds `(?<!{){(.*?)}(?!})`  https://regex101.com/r/EceidW/1

Comment: Or, `Regex.Matches(text, @"{({*[^{}]*}*)}").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value)` ([demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%7b%28%7b*%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d*%7d*%29%7d&i=This+is+a+message+%7bkey1%7d+%7b%7bkey2%7d%7d+%7b%7b%7bkey3%7d%7d%7d%2c+and+includes+%7bkey4%7d.))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is a lot better, that should be it.

Comment: Legends, both work as expected

Comment: What if you have a text with `{{{a}}` (notice the different number of braces)

Comment: And what about `{{{a}} or {{b}}}`? (again, note the different number of opening and closing braces)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen See my comment under Wiktor's answer below.

Comment: Those cases are OK (OP is asking for anything between outer curly braces); the accepted answer handles those cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may get the results you need using

```
var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"{({*[^{}]*}*)}")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value);
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%7B%28%7B%2A%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%2A%7D%2A%29%7D&i=This%20is%20a%20message%20%7Bkey1%7D%20%7B%7Bkey2%7D%7D%20%7B%7B%7Bkey3%7D%7D%7D%2C%20and%20includes%20%7Bkey4%7D.).

**Regex details**

- `{` -  an open curly brace
- `({*[^{}]*}*)` - Group 1:

  - `{*` -  0 or more open curly braces
  - `[^{}]*` - 0 or more chars other than curly braces
  - `}*` -  0 or more close curly braces
- `}` -  a close curly brace

Comment: @OP A simple adjustment to ensure that the number of opening inner braces is equivalent to the number of closing braces: `Regex.Matches(text, @"{(({*)[^{}]*(}*))}").OfType<Match>().Where(m => m.Groups[2].Value.Length == m.Groups[3].Value.Length).Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value);`.

Comment: @41686d6564 In that case, we can still use a plain regex approach: `{((?>[^{}]+|(?<c>{)|(?<-c>}))*)(?(c)(?!))}` ([demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%7b%28%28%3f%3e%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d%2b%7c%28%3f%3cc%3e%7b%29%7c%28%3f%3c-c%3e%7d%29%29*%29%28%3f%28c%29%28%3f!%29%29%7d&i=This+is+a+message+%7bkey1%7d+%7b%7bkey2%7d%7d+%7b%7b%7bkey3%7d%7d%7d%2c+and+includes+%7bkey4%7d.+%7b%7bkey5%7d))

Comment: If anyone can come up with a regex solution, it's you :) I just wanted to provide a simple option without changing the regex pattern completely. Now, if you excuse me for a few minutes while I try to understand how the hell the pattern works :D

Comment: @41686d6564 See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7899205/3832970).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is it possible to further restrict the captures to where the brace count is odd, including 1?

Comment: @rgvlee Please clarify with examples.

Comment: E.g. for the OP string, the matches are key1, key3 and key4 as they have 1 or 3 braces each side. key2 would not be a match as the brace count on at least 1 side is even.

Comment: @rgvlee Then you may use `(?<!{){((?:\{{2})*[^{}]*(?:}{2})*)}(?!})` ([demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%7b%29%7b%28%28%3f%3a%5c%7b%7b2%7d%29*%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d*%28%3f%3a%7d%7b2%7d%29*%29%7d%28%3f!%7d%29&i=This+is+a+message+%7bkey1%7d+%7b%7bkey2%7d%7d+%7b%7b%7bkey3%7d%7d%7d%2c+and+includes+%7bkey4%7d.+%7b%7bkey5%7d))