# A regex expression for multiple brackets opening and closing

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to detect that brackets of different type were properly opened and closed in a string. For instance:

- `"(){}[]"` --> true.
- `"[][{](})"` --> false

I did a try but can't deal with the "false" case:

```
/(\{+\})|(\(+\))|(\[+\])|^$/.test("[][{](})");
```

Any idea?

Comment: Do you *HAVE* to do this with regex?

Comment: Yes, I have to :)

Comment: You can't detect recursive structures via a single regex.

Comment: [Regular expression to match balanced parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/546433) | [Using RegEx to balance match parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7898310)

Comment: If you can apply the same regex repeatedly, you can find and remove every immediately adjacent opening and closing element: `/{}|\[\]|\(\)/`. Once you can't find any more of these, check if the string still has anything in it. If it does, then it has mismatched brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```js
const strings = ["(){}[]", "[][{](})"];
const regex = /\(\)|\[]|{}/g;
strings.forEach(x => { 
  let t = x;
  while (t.match(regex)) t = t.replace(regex, '');
  console.log(x, '=>', t.length == 0);
});
```

Remove all `{}`, `[]` and `()` if  present, check if the string length is 0 or not when there are no more matches.